# Getting No Manifest Detected error while building PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am trying to build a PWA, and in that process have added a manifest file to  of my webpage, but I am getting "No Manifest Detected" in the Application tab in Chrome Dev Tools.

I have seen other threads on this and have tried solutions like restarting, clearing the cache etc. but to no avail.

I tried some other tools like https://manifest-validator.appspot.com/ and they don't seem to show any issues in the manifest file.

You can also try the website at https://beegle.app/apporter-book-help and see that when you do "view source", you can find manifest file added in header and the manifest file link working fine too.

Here's how it has been added

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

Here's how the file looks like:

```
{
  "name": "Beegle Apporter",
  "short_name": "Apporter",
  "icons": [{
    "src": "/beegle-logo-128x128.png",
    "sizes": "128x128",
    "type": "image/png"
  }, {
    "src": "/beegle-logo-144x144.png",
    "sizes": "144x144",
    "type": "image/png"
  }, {
    "src": "/beegle-logo-152x152.png",
    "sizes": "152x152",
    "type": "image/png"
  }, {
    "src": "/beegle-logo-192x192.png",
    "sizes": "192x192",
    "type": "image/png"
  }, {
    "src": "/beegle-logo-256x256.png",
    "sizes": "256x256",
    "type": "image/png"
  }, {
    "src": "/beegle-logo-512x512.png",
    "sizes": "512x512",
    "type": "image/png"
  }],
  "start_url": "/apporter-book-help",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#3E4EB8",
  "theme_color": "#2F3BA2"
}
```

Any suggestions and thoughts on what could be going wrong?

Comment: can you share structure of your project. Manifest file should be at root of your application and if not then you have to use "start_url":"./" and "scope":"/" in manifest files accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Vinod for responding. As you can see from the manifest I have given, it is at the root.

Comment: Lighthouse and the Manifest Validator you linked to seem to be able to find and parse the manifest just fine.

Comment: Yes, that's why I am not able to figure out what is going wrong. Chrome dev tools can't detect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to solve it. I was using some plugin which was adding "body" tag within "head", and somehow that was causing the manifest to not get detected.